# How can I replace the type of Jest expect by the Chai expect?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, chai

I want to use Chai as an assertion library instead of the Jest one. I use typescript and I would like to replace global Jest expect by the type of Chai expect.

I try to do something like:

```
import chai from "chai";

type ChaiExpect = typeof chai.expect;

declare global {
  export const expect: ChaiExpect;
}

global.expect = chai.expect;
```

But typescript complain because:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'expect'.ts(2451)
index.d.ts(39, 15): 'expect' was also declared here.
```

How can I override the type declared inside `index.d.ts` of jest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-assign `global.expect`'s runtime value on javascript side, on the typescript side however, no easy way out.

Jest declares `expect` as a *global variable* (see `@types/jest/index.d.ts(39, 15)`). Currently typescript provides no way to override a *readily declared variable's type in the same block-scope*.

So as long as you keep `@types/jest/index.d.ts` the way it is, nothing you can do to suppress that error.

---

### Solution

#### 1. The easy way

The easiest way to use chai's `expect`, is simply import and use it in every `.test.ts` file:

```js
// sum.test.ts
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { sum } from './sum';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).eq(3)
});
```

#### 2. The hard way

Now if you really can't live with that repeating `import { expect } from 'chai'` line, here's the harder path:

1. Move `node_modules/@types/jest` to `types/jest`, make sure it's gone in the `node_modules` folder. Also delete "@types/jest" from "package.json => devDependencies".
2. Modify `types/jest/index.d.ts`, replace the type of `expect` with chai's. You need to commit this customized type declaration to your git repo.

```
// index.d.ts

+ /// <reference types="chai" />

- declare const expect: Expect
+ declare const expect: Chai.ExpectStatic
```

3. In your `tsconfig.json`, add:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "types"],
    ...
}
```

4. Create `jestSetup.js` and add this one-liner:

```
global.expect = require("chai").expect
```

5. in `jest.config.js`, set:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jestSetup.js'],
// or `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` for older version.
```

There you go. You can now use chai `expect` right in the global scope.